# How to delete multiple history entries from ~/.bash_history using scripts?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, unix, terminal

I wanted to delete commands that are common (such as pwd, ls -l, cd, ) and keep the ones that I might forget how to use. To do this I ran the following commands

```
history | grep "cd$" | cut -c 1-5 > ~/sandboxArea/histDelTemp.txt
cntr=0; for i in $(cat ~/sandboxArea/histDelTemp.txt); do var=`expr $i - $cntr`; history -d $var; cntr=`expr $cntr + 1`; done; unset cntr
```

After running the above command if I again run to check if everything was deleted using the following command

```
history | grep "cd$"
```

then it seems that everything is in fact deleted and the above command produces no output.

However, if I close the terminal and again run the above command then everything seems to re-appear. Why is it so? Does bash has functionality to backup_restore commands?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check if the thread helps -- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49216/402911

Comment: Yes it worked. To write the changes to the history file run: user@linuxbox~$ history -w. So actually I didn't know that we need to write the changes to history file. Thanks